# Simplify the algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Can someone please explain to me how the algebraic expression in the picture is simplified. To be more specific, how (1) becomes (2).

1. $3x^2(6x-4)^4 + x^3(6\times 4\times (6x-4)^3)$
2. $3x^2(6x-4)^3(6x-4+x\times 2\times 4)$
3. $3x^2(6x-4)^3(14x-4)$

original link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXzS.jpg

Comment: When you're factoring from (1) to (2), be very mindful of the term $3x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3x^2(6x-4)^4+x^3(6\times 4\times (6x-4)^3)$$$$=3x^2(6x-4)^3\times(6x-4)+x^2\times x\times 3\times 2\times 4\times (6x-4)^3$$$$=3x^2(6x-4)^3\times(6x-4)+3x^2(6x-4)^3\times x\times 2\times 4$$$$=3x^2(6x-4)^3((6x-4)+x\times 2\times 4)$$

Comment: in the third row what happened to the second $3x^2(6x-4)^3$ ?

Comment: $\color{red}{x^2}\times x\times \color{red}{3}\times 2\times 4\times \color{red}{(6x-4)^3}=\color{red}{3x^2(6x-4)^3}\times x\times 2\times 4$. This is to factor as the fourth row.

Comment: Sorry I meant in the fourth row.

Comment: @manbearpig944: Let $A=3x^2(6x-4)^3,B=6x-4,C=x\times 2\times 4$. Then we have $AB+AC$, right? So, we have $AB+AC=A(B+C)=3x^2(6x-4)^3((6x-4)+x\times 2\times 4)$.